# Tomcat 9 - does gracefulStopAwaitMillis *properly* wait for requests to finish when using non-blocking IO connector?

Tags: tomcat, haproxy

**How does Tomcat 9.0.80+ handle graceful shutdown when using the NIO connector?**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       gracefulStopAwaitMillis="15000" 
       bindOnInit="false" 
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" />
```

I'm already using HAproxy with retries, redispatch and health checks. I have also configured Tomcat to use graceful shutdown and late binding (as per recommendation) to let any reverse proxy/load balancer redispatch to another backend. But I'm unsure if it actually waits for in-process requests to finish processing before exiting. My testing indicates so, but I occasionally get a HTTP 502 from the public facing ALB (TLS, WAF) that sits in-front of HAproxy(advanced routing, API gateway) and then a whole bunch of Tomcat servers that get rolling restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Conclusion

It does **not** guarantee that all requests will be processed!

**As far as I can tell this is what happens:**

1. A request arrives at the reverse proxy and is forwarded to a backend
   server.
2. Th request is placed in a queue and picked up by a thread for processing.
3. Another request is forwarded to Tomcat and is placed in Tomcat's
   request queue.
4. Before it has time to be picked up by a processing thread, a shutdown is initiated.
5. The **original request** that is already being processed by a thread
   **will finish processing** (within the *gracefulStopMillis* timeout).
6. The **second request** is still stuck in the queue and **will be dropped.**
7. The reverse proxy/loadbalancer will encounter a response timeout
   and return a **502** to the client.
8. There is no safe retry the reverse proxy can do unless the application
   is truly idempotent.